# Как запретить повторения в listBox через textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как исключить добавления повторяющихся значений в listBox?

Чтобы при добавлении ничего не происходило или появлялась ошибка.

Comment: Выполните проверку в обработчике кнопки "Добавить". И выводите или не выводите все, что угодно.

Comment: Ну нужно проверит все имеющиеся значения в listbox циклом если равно то ошибка если нет то добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот как пример.

**UPD**

```
int index = listBox1.FindStringExact(textBox1.Text, -1);
   if (index != -1)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
   }
   else
   {
      listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);                        
   }
```

А ну и удаление если понадобиться

```
 int index = listBox1.FindStringExact(textBox1.Text, -1);
   if (index != -1)
   {
       listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);                  
   }
```

Comment: Спасибо, только реагирует на один символ, если это `001` то ввести `0` не дает... и `00` тоже, видимо из за первого символа.

Comment: @Vitokhv обновил.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @Vitokhv не за что)